# Ubuntu GUI in VMWare looks strange

Tags: installation, gui

[image]

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on VMWare and this is how the GUI looks after startup. I re-installed it a couple of time but the problem persists.
First I tried installing while getting the files from the internet, the language packs, etc and when I saw that the GUI is strange,  reinstalled it - this time quick one - without the language packs but the GUI is still messed

I do not know what is causing the problem.
How do I get it to work normally ?

#### Other:

Host OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit
Total RAM : 2GB
RAM allocated to VM : 512 MB.

Comment: it might be helpful to post a screenshot for those willing to help (a) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to install the VMware Tools. It might provide a better video-driver.
Hit "VM" -> "Install VMware-Tools". You have to mount the Disk in Ubuntu, copy and unpack the tools-file an install the tools. Do as root-user:

```
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
cp /mnt/VMwareTools-9.2.2-893683.tar.gz /root
umount /mnt
cd /root
tar -xvzf /root/VMwareTools-9.2.2-893683.tar.gz
cd /root/vmware-tools-distrib/
./vmware-install.pl
rm -rf /root/VMwareTools-9.2.2-893683.tar.gz /root/vmware-install.pl
```

Confirm every question of the installer.
With Ubuntu you should have no trouble. Reboot your VM.

Comment: The problem was that the laptop was on low power graphics. I turned on the graphics card and viola, it works